# Is this an error in the proof of paracompactness of manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, compactness

[image]

This is a theorem from John Lee's book. Here I think that for $V_j$ the index $j$ must start from $0$ instead of $1$ in order to set $V_0=K_1$. Am I correct? Is it that the proof has an error?

Answer (score 1):

There is no error. Since $K_0=\emptyset$,$$V_0=K_1\setminus\mathring{K_0}=K_1\setminus\mathring\emptyset=K_1\setminus\emptyset=K_1.$$

Comment: The proof in the picture does not include such $V_0$